# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter' while saving to an XML file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, attributeerror

I want to save settings preferences to an XML file and for the first time it works. I mean when I check the checkbox for the first after starting the program it saves everything to file without any errors but when I check the checkbox second time to save OTHER values it raises `AttributeError`. Here is my code:

```py
        if self.autoUpdateCheck.isChecked():
            data = ET.Element('settings')
            item1 = ET.SubElement(data, 'autoUpdate')
            item2 = ET.SubElement(data, 'autoCheckVer')
            item1.set('value', 'True')
            if self.autoUpdateCheck.isChecked():
                item2.set('value', 'True')
            else:
                item2.set('value', 'False')
            mydata = ET.tostring(data).decode("utf-8")
            file = open("settings.xml", 'w')
            file.write(mydata)
        else:
            data = ET.Element('settings')
            item1 = ET.SubElement(data, 'autoUpdate')
            item2 = ET.SubElement(data, 'autoCheckVer')
            item1.set('value', 'False')
            if self.autoUpdateCheck.isChecked():
                item2.set('value', 'True')
            else:
                item2.set('value', 'False')
            mydata = ET.tostring(data).decode("utf-8")
            file = open("settings.xml", 'w')
            file.write(ET.tostring(mydata))
```

**EDIT:** Here is the full Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/PythonProjects/PythonFTP/ftpdl.py", line 228, in auto_update_set
>       file.write(ET.tostring(mydata))   File "C:\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1136, in tostring
>       short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)   File "C:\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 774, in write
>       qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)   File "C:\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 877, in
>   _namespaces
>       for elem in elem.iter(): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'

Comment: Please paste the full error traceback. The error traceback tells you EXACTLY what line is causing the issue making it easier to find the problem. Also you never close your file.

Comment: I edited the question now. Traceback included.

Comment: `mydata` is already a string. You made it a string two lines earlier: `mydata = ET.tostring(data).decode("utf-8")`. Because it is a string, using `ET.tostring(mydata)` fails. Remove the `ET.tostring()` call in the `file.write(...)` line.